# How to read in Excel file with pandas that does not only contain data?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am wondering if there is any way to read in Excel files using pandas where the first 3-5 rows consist of an info text?

I know about skipping the first rows using the `skiprows=3` and `header=[3]` params in `pd.read_excel`, but is there a way to read out the information of the first rows and saving it in a variable as well as taking the let's say fifth row as headline?

Example .xlsx:

```
0 Name: John
1 Age:  27
2 This is just some text
3 Fruit      Color
4 Banana     yellow
5 Coconut    brown
6 Strawberry red
```

=> Some elegant way to get the information rows 0-2 and rows 3-6 as a separate pandas.dataframe with line 3 as headline?

I tried to read in the full excel file without headline, split it, resetting the index and to treat the two data frames separately, but this wasn't very successful as well.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you tried even if it didn't work.

Comment: But I think my approach would be to open the file twice. First, call `pd.read_excel` with `nrows=2` to read the first two rows in one call, then use `skiprows` to get the structured data in the second call.

Comment: I thought of just opening the file twice and did not do it because of the additional file access time, but reading it once only to the second line is a good solution as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open("example.csv") as f:
line = next(f)
while line != "\n":
    print(line)
    line = next(f)
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print(df)
```

You open the file with the "with" statement and iterate until your header is sepererated (e.g. "\n"). Then you pass the Generator (f) to your pandas.read_csv or read_exel.

Comment: this would be great if i had a .csv, but I could mention to convert it first and treat the csv file as you suggested. Thanks for the nice idea!